# Error while running node-solr client

Tags: node.js, solr

guys I am trying to run the example given on github in the following link.

https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client

My port on which Solr runs is 8080.

Any of the files given in the examples directory I run gives the following error

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this source code - https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client/blob/master/lib/solr.js

solr uses 8983 port by default

create client with 8080 port, something like......

```
createClient('127.0.0.1', 8080, '', '/solr')
```

Comment: where in the world did you find docs on the params possible for createClient()?  I don't see anything on their docs specifying the params

Comment: Follow the link to source code. All the params are explained in detail.

Comment: Do i need to start solr also ?